# Как изменить цвет(прогресса/фона) ProgressBarEdit?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

На сайте DevExpress в [документации](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ProgressBarEdit.AdditionalForeground.property) для v.17.2 (я использую DevExpress v15.2, но другой нет и раньше отличий не проявлялось) указано, что якобы цвет некой *левой* *части* задаётся свойством `AdditionalForeground`.

> ProgressBarEdit.AdditionalForeground Property.
>
> Specifies the color of the left side of the ProgressBarEdit. This is a dependency property.

а цвет некой *правой* *части* задаёт `Foreground`.

> To specify the color of the right side of the ProgressBarEdit, use the Foreground property.

Проблема в том, что оно не работает — только Foreground задаёт цвет текста, отображаемого поверх контрола; задание св-ва Background тоже ничего не меняет.
Т__Т

XAML:

```
<dxe:ProgressBarEdit Name="fact1" Background="Red"  Foreground="Red" AdditionalForeground ="Red" Value="77" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="ФАКТ" ShowBorder="False" ContentDisplayMode="Content" IsPercent="True">
    <dxe:ProgressBarEdit.StyleSettings>
        <dxe:ProgressBarStyleSettings />
    </dxe:ProgressBarEdit.StyleSettings>
</dxe:ProgressBarEdit>
```

[image: выглядит он так, к сожалению]

Подскажите, как изменить цвет(прогресса/фона)? Либо что тогда за *левая*/*правая* *части* имелись в виду?

Comment: Может стоит добавить немного кода в вопрос ну и маленькую картинку,  с тем что получилось или что хотите...

Comment: @DenisBubnov  эт можно конешн, но не особо много информации это добавит.    
Успел посмотреть немного ваш отменённый ответ.... ага, у меня именно **Edit**, а не **Control** -- соответственно, таких свойств я не наблюдаю  =__=  и такого DE-элемента "ProgressBarControl" в списке доступных тоже нет.

Comment: Да, немного не по тому элементу был ответ, но я его обновил для `ProgressBarEdit`. Загляните в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо переопределить `PanelBackgroundHorizontalTemplate` и `PanelLeftSideHorizontalTemplate`, чтобы изменить цвет для индикатора выполнения и управления фоном в элементе управления `ProgressBarEdit`.

Пример кода:

```
<dx:DXWindow
    x:Class="DXWPFApplication31.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DXWPFApplication31"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxet="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors/themekeys"
    Title="DXApplication" Height="185" Width="449"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="MetropolisDark" 
    xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
    >

    <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelBackgroundHorizontalTemplate, IsThemeIndependent=true}"  TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Border>
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="Aqua"/> <!--set background-->
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelLeftSideHorizontalTemplate}" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Border Margin="1" CornerRadius="2">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <!--<GradientStop Color="#FF6389C1" Offset="0.004" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7095CA" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF305897" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF244985" Offset="0.5" />-->
                        <GradientStop Color="Green"/><!--set background-->
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxet:ProgressBarEditStyleThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelTemplateHorizontal, IsThemeIndependent=true}" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:RangeEditBasePanel}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="root">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <dxe:GridLengthConverter x:Key="GridLengthConverter" />
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="leftColumn" Width="{Binding Path=(dxe:RangeEditBaseInfo.LayoutInfo).LeftSidePosition, Converter={StaticResource GridLengthConverter}}" />
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="rightColumn" Width="{Binding Path=(dxe:RangeEditBaseInfo.LayoutInfo).RightSidePosition, Converter={StaticResource GridLengthConverter}}" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="back" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource {dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelBackgroundHorizontalStyle}}" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="left" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource {dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelLeftSideHorizontalStyle}}" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="right" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource {dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelRightSideHorizontalStyle}}" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="foreground" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource {dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=PanelForegroundStyle}}" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentControl x:Name="PART_InnerContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource {dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=ContentStyle}}"  Content="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).DisplayText}" ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).ContentTemplate}">
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>

        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="{dxet:ProgressBarEditThemeKey ResourceKey=ContentStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#993333">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <dxe:ProgressBarEdit Value="33" 
                             Orientation="Horizontal" 
                             Margin="102,37,96,0" 
                             ContentDisplayMode="Content"/>

    </Grid>

</dx:DXWindow>
```

Ссылка на источник: [Can't change color of BAR in ProgessBarEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T194919/can-t-change-color-of-bar-in-progessbaredit)

А также:

- [Change ProgressBarEdit Color doesn't work](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q494096/change-progressbaredit-color-doesn-t-work)
- [How to change ProgressBarEdit's progress color depending on the Value property](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q497712/how-to-change-progressbaredit-s-progress-color-depending-on-the-value-property)
- [ProgressBarEdit Color](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T356968/progressbaredit-color)

Comment: как определяются цепочки(`Path`) для прямой привязки(`Binding`) свойств к существующим исходно?    т.е. я пытаюсь просто привязать цвет `<Border.Background>`... `Color="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).AdditionalForeground}"` -- и вроде как явной ошибки нет, но и ничего не получается, пустота вместо кисти